# How to get rid of this implicit conversion?

Tags: json, scala, implicit-conversion, json4s

Suppose I am using `json4s` to parse JSON:

```
val str = """{"a":"aaaa", "x": 0}"""
val json = JsonMethods.parse(str)
val a = for(JObject(fields) <- json; JField("a", JString(a)) <- fields) yield a
```

The type of `a` is `List[String]` but I need `Option[String]`, so I am calling `headOption`:

```
val a = (
  for(JObject(fields) <- json; JField("a", JString(a)) <- fields) yield a
).headOption
```

Since I found myself calling `headOption` again and again I tried an *implicit conversion*:

```
object X { implicit def foo[A](as: List[A]): Option[A] = as.headOption }
import X.foo
val a: Option[String] = 
  for(JObject(fields) <- json; JField("a", JString(a)) <- fields) yield a
```

The implicit conversion is working but I don't like it. What would you suggest ?

Comment: I'd suggest abstracting out the logic of the decoding part so that you only have to call `headOption` in a single place (but a place that isn't in an implicit conversion).

Comment: @TravisBrown Thank you for the comment. I will think how to do it.

Comment: What about the `\` operator and manipulating all the json stuff in the middle before finally calling `toOption`?

Comment: @badcook I did not get it. Could you give an example ?

Comment: Oops I didn't escape that operator correctly. I meant to write \. I don't know if you're just trying to access fields. If you are you could write something like `getOpt(jsObj, key) = (jsObj \ key).toOption`.

Comment: @badcook The problem with `getOpt` is type conversion. `getOpt` returns `Option[JValue]` while I need `Option[A]` where `A` is a `String`, `Int`, etc.

Comment: Hmmm... well you could do something like `getOpt[A](jsObj: JObject, key: A): A = Try{(jsObj \ key).extract[A]}.toOption`.

Comment: I am afraid `extract` uses runtime reflection. Besides it looks a little noisy.

Comment: While you're looking at JSON libraries, also might be worth checking out circe or Argonaut (especially as the author of the former is @TravisBrown).

Comment: Thank you, I know about these libraries. Hope to use `circe` in future.

Comment: for-comprehension for traversal is not feasible here. Also there is `extractOpt`: so you can do `(json \ "a").extractOpt[String]`

Comment: What is exactly non feasible ? `extractOpt` uses runtime reflection I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that you didnt want reflection. Read the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use json4's typeclasses, e.g. [json4s-scalaz](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/tree/3.4/scalaz) has those:

```
trait JSONR[A] {
  def read(json: JValue): Result[A]
}

trait JSONW[A] {
  def write(value: A): JValue
}
```

[source](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/3.4/scalaz/src/main/scala/org/json4s/scalaz/JsonScalaz.scala#L43-L49)

For syntactic simplicity one can define extensions methods for `JValue`:

```
implicit class JValueOps(value: JValue) {
  def validate[A: JSONR]: ValidationNel[Error, A] = implicitly[JSONR[A]].read(value)
  def read[A: JSONR]: Error \/ A = implicitly[JSONR[A]].read(value).disjunction.leftMap(_.head)
}
```

And then do a traversal and also parse the resulting `JValue` of the traversal like this:

```
val str =
  """
    |{
    |  "a": "aaaa",
    |  "x": 0
    |}""".stripMargin

val json = parseJson(str)

(json \ "a").read[Option[String]]
// \/-(Some(aaaa))

(json \ "b").read[Option[String]]
// \/-(None)

(json \ "a").validate[Option[String]]
// Success(Some(aaaa))

(json \ "b").validate[Option[String]]
// Success(None)
```

Defining your own `JSONR[A]`/`JSONW[A]` instances (and putting them in implicit scope) is possible like this:

```
case class MyA(a: Option[String], x: Int)

implicit val myARead: JSONR[MyA] = JSON.readE[MyA] { json =>
  for {
    a <- (json \ "a").read[Option[String]]
    x <- (json \ "x").read[Int]
  } yield MyA(a, x)
}

implicit val myAWrite: JSONW[MyA] = JSON.write[MyA] { myA =>
  ("a" -> myA.a) ~
    ("x" -> myA.x)
}


json.read[MyA]
// \/-(MyA(Some(aaaa),0))

json.validate[MyA]
// Success(MyA(Some(aaaa),0))

MyA(Some("aaaa"), 0).toJson
// JObject(List((a,JString(aaaa)), (x,JInt(0))))
```

Note that the `read[A]` and `write[a]` methods are glue code which is not in json4s-scalaz available yet, you can find the source [here](https://github.com/dozed/json4s-drafts/tree/master/src/main/scala/drafts). There are also more [examples](https://github.com/dozed/json4s-drafts/tree/master/src/test/scala).

Then `json.read[A]` returns a [`Error \/ A`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/tests/src/test/scala/scalaz/DisjunctionTest.scala) and `json.validate[A]` yields a [`Validation`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/tests/src/test/scala/scalaz/ValidationTest.scala) types from [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz). There are similar types in [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats).

`myARead` is an example of monadic parsing style (compose via flatMap). An alternative uses applicative parsing. This has the benefit that all validation errors are accumulated:

```
val myARead2: JSONR[MyA] = JSON.read[MyA] { json =>
  (
    (json \ "a").validate[Option[String]] |@|
    (json \ "x").validate[Int]
  ).tupled.map(MyA.tupled)
}


val myARead3: JSONR[MyA] = JSON.read[MyA] {
  for {
    a <- field[Option[String]]("a") _
    x <- field[Int]("x") _
  } yield (a |@| x).tupled.map(MyA.tupled)
}
```

There is also https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/3.4/core/src/main/scala/org/json4s/JsonFormat.scala

Comment: Thanks for reminding of json4s-scalaz ! I am afraid I am not a big fan of that approach though. I will think about another solution (maybe as in `circe` but on top of `json4s`).

Comment: @Michael What problems do you see?

Comment: Well, this is probably a matter of taste but ... why do I need `trait` and `implicit class` if I can do with just simple functions:  `JValue => Error \/ A` or `JValue => Validation[Error, A]` ?

Comment: Besides, how can I get `JSONR[AB]` for `case class AB(a: A, b: B)` given `JSONR[A]` and `JSONR[B]` automatically in compile time ?

Comment: The trait/class are only library code, you dont need them. In userland you actually work with those functions you mentioned. Take a closer look. Also typeclasses are ideal for composition, `myARead` is based on `JSONR[Option[String]` and `JSONR[Int]`. Its pretty cool.

Comment: A macro to derive a `JSONR[A]` can be found here https://github.com/dozed/json4s-drafts/blob/master/src/main/scala/drafts/Macros.scala#L22-L46. Writing a `JSONW[A]` is still on my todo.

Comment: I added a `JSONR[A]` using shapeless' LabelledTypeClass https://github.com/dozed/json4s-drafts/blob/master/src/test/scala/ParseExample3.scala#L22

Comment: Thanks again. I will take a closer look on using `JSONR` and their composability. `JSONR` with `shapeless` is interesting too !